# Can't access any USB drive Windows 7 though loggedin as admin

Tags: windows-7, usb, user-accounts

I work in company where some one had make changes in my pc. Because of this I can't access any usb drive, Windows detects usb drive but when clicked message pop out

> F:/ is not accessible, access denied"

I'm already logged in as administrator I tried reinstalling driver but doesn't fix my problem

One other thing,when I go to control panel it only shows two user accounts

- administrator
- guest

But when I right click any hard drive -> properties -> security it shows me one more account with name SystemCreator

Comment: Contact your IT personal for assistance with a company computer. What exact changes were made? **Sounds like a group policy change.  If thats the case it doesn't matter if you are an administrator.**

Answer (score 0):

your administrator must have blocked USB. as far as system account is concerned it is a special account in windows that is simply above all. It has all the privileges and is used by the OS to perform certain tasks.

From MS :

> The system account and the administrator account (Administrators group) have the same file privileges, but they have different functions. The system account is used by the operating system and by services that run under Windows. There are many services and processes within Windows that need the capability to log on internally (for example during a Windows installation). The system account was designed for that purpose; it is an internal account, does not show up in User Manager, cannot be added to any groups, and cannot have user rights assigned to it. On the other hand, the system account does show up on an NTFS volume in File Manager in the Permissions portion of the Security menu. By default, the system account is granted full control to all files on an NTFS volume. Here the system account has the same functional privileges as the administrator account.